# MVC 5 DropDownListFor postback null

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, razor

I am trying to create cascading dropdownlist using @Html.DropDownListFor helper and jQuery AJAX. The first load is always perfect. all dropdownlist data was displayed correctly. However, after postback, it always hit ModelState.IsValid = False and the dropdownlist become empty. Below is my code:

Model

```
Public Property Province As New List(Of SelectListItem)
Public Property City As New List(Of SelectListItem)
Public Property SelectedProvince As String
Public Property SelectedCity As String
```

Controller

```
Public Function SetEmployeeProfile() As ActionResult
    Dim loc As New clsLocation
    Dim provinces As List(Of Province)
    Dim model As New SetEmployeeProfileViewModel

    provinces = loc.GetProvinceList
    Dim sel As SelectListItem

    For Each p As Province In provinces
        sel = New SelectListItem
        sel.Text = p.ProvinceName
        sel.Value = p.ProvinceName
        model.Province.Add(sel)
    Next

    Return View(model)    

End Function
```

View

```
@ModelType SetEmployeeProfileViewModel

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(Function(m) m.Province, New With {.class = "col-md-2 control-label"})
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(Function(m) m.Province, New SelectList(Model.Province, "Value", "Text", Model.SelectedProvince), New With {.class = "form-control"})
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(m) m.Province, "", New With {.class = "text-danger"})
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(Function(m) m.City, New With {.class = "col-md-2 control-label"})
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(Function(m) m.City, New SelectList(Model.City, "Value", "Text", Model.SelectedCity), New With {.class = "form-control"})
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(m) m.City, "", New With {.class = "text-danger"})
        </div>
    </div>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    LoadCities();
});

$("#Province").change(function () {
    LoadCities();
});

function LoadCities() {
    var selectedItem = $("#Province").val();
    var ddlCities = $("#City");
    var statesProgress = $("#city-loading-progress");
    statesProgress.show();
    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        type: "POST",
        url: "@(Url.Action("GetCities"))",
        data: { "provinceName": selectedItem },
        success: function (data) {
            ddlCities.html('');
            $.each(data, function (id, option) {
                ddlCities.append($('<option></option>').val(option.CityName).html(option.CityName));
            });
            statesProgress.hide();
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert('Failed to retrieve cities.');
            statesProgress.hide();
        }
    });
}
```

NOTE: I tried adding selectedProvince property in the model and implemented according to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16058539/mvc-dropdownlistfor-null-values) but the problem still persist. Both Province and City field also produces the following validation error:

```
The value 'Bali' is invalid.  (Province)
The value 'Kuta' is invalid.  (City)
```

The URL after postback is:
    https://localhost:55500/Employee/SetEmployeeProfile?Sex=M&Dob=01%2F01%2F0001%2000%3A00%3A00&Province=System.Collections.Generic.List%601%5BSystem.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem%5D&City=System.Collections.Generic.List%601%5BSystem.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem%5D

Is it normal that it put query string: Province=System.Collections.Generic.List ?

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake is here

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(Function(m) m.Province, New SelectList(Model.Province, "Value", "Text", Model.SelectedProvince), New With {.class = "form-control"})
```

and here

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(Function(m) m.City, New SelectList(Model.City, "Value", "Text", Model.SelectedCity), New With {.class = "form-control"})
```

The first parameter of `@Html.DropDownListFor()` for the first dropdownlist should be `Function(m) m.SelectedProvince` instead of `Function(m) m.Province`, and for the second dropdownlist should be `Function(m) m.SelectedCity` instead of `Function(m) m.City`.

Below is the changed portion of code:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(Function(m) m.Province, New With {.class = "col-md-2 control-label"})
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(Function(m) m.SelectedProvince, New SelectList(Model.Province, "Value", "Text", Model.SelectedProvince), New With {.class = "form-control"})
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(m) m.Province, "", New With {.class = "text-danger"})
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(Function(m) m.City, New With {.class = "col-md-2 control-label"})
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(Function(m) m.SelectedCity, New SelectList(Model.City, "Value", "Text", Model.SelectedCity), New With {.class = "form-control"})
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(m) m.City, "", New With {.class = "text-danger"})
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. As I mentioned above, I've tried using Function(m) m.SelectedProvince according to another post on stackoverflow with no luck. I confirmed again after modifying the code to follow your solution and the form error message is: The value 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem]' is invalid. And there is no value on the dropdownlist after postback. Once again terima kasih banyak for helping :)

Comment: This answer is correct, and if its not working you have other errors in your code. The url your claiming suggests you also have a hidden input for property `Province` and `City` or have tried to include the model in `BeginForm` as  route parameter. And there is no point creating another `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` in the view when properties `Province` and `City` are already `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`